# Selenium list size printed in table using java

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently, I am working one project where I print table one my testNG emailable report
the problem is I am not getting the way that how to divide it on another row? Like every 13 row, a new row will start and I will give the one-row name.Thanks for supporting me

```
@Test
public void Oz_Stays_dashboard() throws InterruptedException {
    wd.manage().window().maximize();

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-form']/div[4]/input")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mws-navigation']/ul/li[1]/a/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")).click();
    wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mws-navigation']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Reporter.log("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    Reporter.log("<html>");
    Reporter.log("<head>");
    Reporter.log("<style>");
    Reporter.log("table, th, td {");
    Reporter.log(" border: 1px solid black;");
    Reporter.log("border-collapse: collapse;");
    Reporter.log("}");
    Reporter.log("th, td {");
    Reporter.log("padding: 5px;");
    Reporter.log("text-align: left;");
    Reporter.log("}");
    Reporter.log("</style>");
    Reporter.log("  </head>");
    Reporter.log("<body>");
    Reporter.log("<table>");
    Reporter.log(" <tr>");
     Reporter.log("<th>Ad Rev.</th>");
     Reporter.log("<th>Lead Rev.</th>");
     Reporter.log("<th>Booking Rev.</th>");
     Reporter.log("<th>Homeaway Rev.</th>");
     Reporter.log("<th>VRBO Rev.</th>");
     Reporter.log("<th>Hotels.com Rev.</th>");
     Reporter.log("<th>Airbnb Rev.</th>");
     Reporter.log("<th>Total Projected Rev.</th>");
     Reporter.log("<th>Ad Spend</th>");
     Reporter.log("<th>G.Profit</th>");
     Reporter.log("<th>G.Margin</th>");
     Reporter.log("<th>Ad Rev/Spend</th>");
     Reporter.log("<th>ROAS</th>");
     Reporter.log(" <tr>");      
     List<WebElement> rhrev = wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='mws-stat-value']"));           

    int size=rhrev.size();
            **for(WebElement e : rhrev) {
    String clink=e.getText();
    System.out.println(clink);

    Reporter.log("<th>"+clink+ "</th>");

    }**
    Reporter.log(" </tr>");
    Reporter.log("</table>");
    Reporter.log("</body>");
    Reporter.log("</html>");
```

and here is my current Output
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace below code in your class

```
int count =1;
String clink=null;
List<WebElement> rhrev = wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='mws-stat-value']"));           
int size=rhrev.size();

for(WebElement e : rhrev) 
{
    clink=e.getText();
    System.out.println(clink);

    if(count<=13)
    {
        Reporter.log("<td>"+clink+ "</td>");
        count++;
    }
    else
    {

        count=1;
        clink=e.getText();
        Reporter.log(" </tr>");
        Reporter.log(" <tr>"); 
        Reporter.log("<td>"+clink+ "</td>");
        count++;
    }
}
```

You need to add add new ROW after every 13th column. This code will help. I have tested at my end, its working fine. If face any issue let me know :)

Complete Code would be :

```
Reporter.log("<!DOCTYPE html>");
Reporter.log("<html> <head> <style> table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }");
Reporter.log("th, td { padding: 5px; text-align: left; }");
Reporter.log("</style> </head>");
Reporter.log("<body> <table> <tr>");
Reporter.log("<th>Ad Rev.</th> <th>Lead Rev.</th> <th>Booking Rev.</th> <th>Homeaway Rev.</th> <th>VRBO Rev.</th>");
Reporter.log("<th>Hotels.com Rev.</th> <th>Airbnb Rev.</th> <th>Total Projected Rev.</th> <th>Ad Spend</th> <th>G.Profit</th> <th>G.Margin</th> <th>Ad Rev/Spend</th> <th>ROAS</th>");
Reporter.log(" <tr>");      
List<WebElement> rhrev = wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='mws-stat-value']"));           
int count =1;
String clink=null;
for(WebElement e : rhrev)
{
    if(count<=13)
    {
        clink=e.getText();
        System.out.println(clink);
        Reporter.log("<td>"+clink+ "</td>");
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        count=1;
        clink=e.getText();
        Reporter.log(" </tr> <tr>");
        Reporter.log("<td>"+clink+ "</td>");
        count++;                      
    }                 
}
Reporter.log(" </tr> </table> </body> </html>");
```

Comment: Thanks tuks for your help.It's working but the problem in 13 number column print 2 times.same column I am getting 13 and 1 number column

Comment: is it inserting the right value in table ? or there is also same issue as in printing ?

Comment: I have attached an image.Can you please check? It's show 1st row 13 number column and  2nd row 1st column same value Also
2nd row 13 number column and  3rd row 1st column same value..But its different

Comment: @zsbappa, I have update the answer now check. just added `clink=e.getText();` in `else` block

Answer (score 0):

how about adding one more loop for column

```
    for(WebElement e : rhrev) {
        String clink=e.getText();
        System.out.println(clink);
        Reporter.log("<tr>");
        for (int col=0; col< 13; col++){
            Reporter.log("<td>"+clink+ "</td>");    
        }
        Reporter.log("<tr>");

    }
```